# Wordpress Revolution Slider Custom For Pages

Tags: php, if-statement, wordpress, slider

I need to show "homepage" slider on homepage and "whitetop" slider on all other pages. I put the PHP code of slider on header.php but both sliders are showing on all pages. How can I do it with IF ELSE conditions so homepage will show homepage slider and other pages show "whitetop" slider? Can you help me in this?

My sliders code:`<?php putRevSlider("whitetop") ?>
<?php putRevSlider("homepage") ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved it by just using the Wordpress conditional tags.

'

```
<?php
if ( is_front_page() ) :
putRevSlider("homepage");
else :
putRevSlider("whitetop");
endif;
?>'
```

I put the is_front_page condition as "if" and put my homepage slider and then in "else" condition I put whitetop slider, that's it!